# Golang package dependencies issues

Tags: go, go-modules

I would like to use the following function in my controller https://github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/blob/05041eaab5a6b9e22dd26df421d8d51050c39072/pkg/controller/vsphere/util.go#L221
Thefore in my code I do the following import

```
package controllers

import (
    "context"

    vsphere "github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller"
    corev1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/types"
    "sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/client"
)
```

However, when I do go mod tidy, I get the following error:

```
bitbucket.bit.admin.ch/BOSC/bosc-drs-vm-group-controller/controllers imports
        github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller imports
        github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller/machinehealthcheck imports
        sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api/pkg/apis/cluster/v1alpha1: module sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api@latest found (v1.3.2), but does not contain package sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api/pkg/apis/cluster/v1alpha1
bitbucket.bit.admin.ch/BOSC/bosc-drs-vm-group-controller/controllers imports
        github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller imports
        github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller/machinehealthcheck imports
        github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/apis/healthchecking/v1alpha1 imports
        sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/runtime/scheme: module sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@latest found (v0.14.1), but does not contain package sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/runtime/scheme
```

It seems that there are some dependencies issues, however I am not sure how to solve them. I tried in go.mod to set sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime to reference a branch and not to latest, but it doesn't seem that it has any effect.

```
require (
    ...
)

require (
    ...
    sigs.k8s.io/cluster-api release-1.3 //indirect
    
)
```

How am I suppose to solve package dependencies issues?

Comment: You've imported `github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller` and aliased it `vsphere`, when according to your explanation you want to import `github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller/vsphere`. Other than that, it's possible that the mainline of the module you're using has a broken dependency graph.

Comment: So if I import github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller/vsphere, I get the following message: github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller/vsphere: module github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator@latest found (v0.2.0), but does not contain package github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller/vsphere. Maybe that's why then I tried to import only github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller. Still it is not clear to me how this work...

Comment: Then the package does not exist in `v0.2.0`. If you need that exact code, you may need to specify the branch or commit.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
go get github.com/openshift/machine-api-operator/pkg/controller/vsphere@master
```

That package is not available in @latest release.